# Node: Google Drive API for listing all files using query

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api

May I know how can I list all the files using query in the Google Drive using the GoogleAPIS library

https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/

I have no idea, how to use this library!

I dont know where should I place my query, I have tried the code below, but I am not getting any response..

Test 1:

```
drive.files.list("mimeType='image/jpg'", function(data){
    //I am getting all the data, the query is not working..
));
```

Test 2:

```
drive.files.list({
    media: {
        mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
    }
}, function(err, data){
    //I am getting all the data, the query is not working..
});
```

Test 3:

```
drive.files.list({
    resource: {
        mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
    }
}, function(err, data){
    //This returns error not working at all!
});
```

Comment: Have you tried reading? https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

Comment: @DaImTo of course I have read them, but the Javascript sample provided is not using the GoogleAPIs node library...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the drive.files.list function given here https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/apis/drive/v2.js#L733 and use something like the following for it.

```
var drive = google.drive({ version: 'v2', auth: oauth2Client });
drive.files.list({
   q='mimeType='image/jpg''
 }, callback);
```

More details on the input parameters for the list function are on https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

Comment: yup tried that too! but not working! i have edited my questiosn

Comment: i could get image file, but i have problem when i try to search for folder, i am not getting any data.. q: "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'", i got empty array...

Comment: First check your scope. It's possible that the folder you're looking for is outside of the granted scope, eg. if you have drive.file scope, but the folder wasn't created by your app. Next check the nextPageToken in the response. It's possible to receive an empty array, in conjunction with a nextPageToken telling you that there are more results. Finally, it's always worth considering coding to the REST API directly. The library is in Alpha, so possibly not the most stable/reliable access mechanism.

Comment: page not found for https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/apis/drive/v2.js#L733